How to insert int128 data to Cickhouse with ClickHouseHook?
I'm using ClickHouseHook for insert data to databse.
from airflow_clickhouse_plugin.hooks.clickhouse import ClickHouseHook

ch_hook = ClickHouseHook(clickhouse_conn_id=connections_name)

def update_replacingmergetree(ch_hook, table_name: str, df: pd.DataFrame):
    values = tuple(df.to_records(index=False))
    ch_hook.execute(f'INSERT INTO do_you.{table_name} VALUES', (v for v in values))

My function works fine, then DataFrame don't contains dates.
But then I pass data like this (part of tuple with values):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   id     18 non-null     string        
 1   s_id    18 non-null     int32         
 2   month_date  18 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 3   sum    18 non-null     int32   





id
s_id
month_date
sum




0
265609333301876169530781520669667823585
84
2024-01-01 00:00:00
100



I get error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

To avoid this error I need convert id to int128, but I can't do that, cause pandas or numpy don't have int128 type.
How to put int128 value to Clickhouse?

I solved problem with this code with apply to every column with big number:
# column must containg 'string' type, not 'object'
df = df.astype({'column': 'string'}
# converting to int128 (in df.info() i still see 'string' type
df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: int(x, 10))
# but in tuple with values I will have int128 type
values = tuple(df.to_records(index=False))

Full code:
def update_replacingmergetree(ch_hook, table_name: str, df: pd.DataFrame):
    df = df.astype({'column': 'string'}
    df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: int(x, 10))
    values = tuple(df.to_records(index=False))
    ch_hook.execute(f'INSERT INTO do_you.{table_name} VALUES', (v for v in values))

